# CS0246: The type or namespace name `T' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, generics, data-structures, generic-programming

I am working on c# and am beginner. I am under a situation that I am creating Huffman tree where I calculate the frequency of the symbols in a binary file (I mean number of times the symbol repeats is the frequency).I tried to make this "symbol" work for all data types like `int`, `short`,`ulong` etc. I do so using generics.

And I then I tried to run the code I am getting 4 errors like :

```
CS0246: The type or namespace name `T' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

I know compiler is not able to recognize this "`T`" but before "`T`" I was using just `public class Node<K>` instead of `public class Node<T> where T : K` so that time the error was :

```
z.cs(13,23): warning CS0693: Type parameter `K' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type `shekhar_final_version_Csharp.Huffman<K>'
z.cs(10,18): (Location of the symbol related to previous warning)
```

So I was obliged to replace this "`K`" with equivalent "`T`". But now the error grown to be 4 (similar):

```
z.cs(20,21): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `T' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
z.cs(72,38): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `T' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
z.cs(83,21): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `T' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
z.cs(267,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `T' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

My full code is:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class Huffman<K> where K :  IComparable<K>
{
    public int data_size, length, i, is_there;
Line 13: public class Node<T> where T : K
    {
        public Node<T> next, left, right;
        public K symbol;
        public int freq;
        public int is_processed;
    }
Line 20: public Node<T> front, rear;
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    public Huffman(string[] args) 
    {
        front = null;
        rear = null;
        using(var stream = new BinaryReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(args[0]))) 
        {
            while (stream.BaseStream.Position < stream.BaseStream.Length) 
            {
                int processingValue = stream.ReadByte(); 
                {
                    Node<T> pt, temp;
                    bool is_there = false;
                    pt = front;
                    while (pt != null) 
                    {
                        if (pt.symbol == processingValue) 
                        {
                            pt.freq++;
                            is_there = true;

                            break;
                        }
                        temp = pt;
                        pt = pt.next;
                    }
                    if (is_there == false) 
                    {
                        temp = new Node<T>();
                        temp.symbol = processingValue;
                        temp.freq = 1;
                        temp.left = null;
                        temp.right = null;
                        temp.next = null;
                        temp.is_processed = 0;
                        if (front == null) 
                        {
                            front = temp;
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            temp.next = front;
                            front = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            stream.Close();
            //////////////////////////////
        }
    }
}
```

Could some one please help me in removing these errors ? I would really appreciate. But please remember if I do "`public class Node<K>`" instead of  "`public class Node<T> where T : K`" in Line 13. It gives these errors:

```
z.cs(13,23): warning CS0693: Type parameter `K' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type `shekhar_final_version_Csharp.Huffman<K>'
z.cs(10,18): (Location of the symbol related to previous warning)
```

Comment: aside from Jon's excellent answer, it might probably be worth noting that it's often useful to provide more meaningful names to generic type arguments, especially if you have more than one - e.g. `ICopyContents<TSource, TTarget>` instead of `ICopyContents<T,K>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at a massively reduced version of this:

```
public class Huffman<K>
{
    public class Node<T> where T : K
    {
    }

    public Node<T> front, rear;
}
```

What is the type of `front` and `rear` here? It refers to `T`, but we have no idea what `T` is. `T` is a type *parameter* in `Node<T>`, but when you have the declaration of a field you need to provide a type *argument*.

I suspect you actually want:

```
public Node<K> front, rear;
```

It be honest it's not clear that you need `Node` to be a generic class at all. I suspect you could probably be fine with:

```
public class Huffman<K>
{
    public class Node
    {
        // You can still use K here...
    }

    public Node front, rear;
}
```

Think about whether you *really* need to two different type parameters here - where's the benefit in doing so?

Comment: What i actually want to achieve is that in my node class i have "symbol" and this symbol is read from binary file (and frequency is number of times this symbol repeats)(In binary file we have symbols  like "11010101" etc.). I want this symbol to make work not just for "int" but also "short", "ulong" etc. on 32/64 bit architecture. I have just tested it on "int" and it works on "int" properly but i wanted to make it work also on other data types. Can still achieve it by doing : public class Huffman<K>
{ public class Node{..}public Node front, rear;}? Could you please give any algorithm ?

Comment: I can make that algorith as reference. And yes you were right I wanted to do "public Node<K> front, rear;"

Comment: These are the 6 errors i have obtained when i remove <T> (as you suggested me to do).:

Comment: z.cs(37,43): error CS0019: Operator `==' cannot be applied to operands of type `K' and `int'
z.cs(50,41): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to `K'
z.cs(283,21): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `K' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
z.cs(285,13): error CS0841: A local variable `ObjSym' cannot be used before it is declared
z.cs(286,13): error CS0841: A local variable `ObjSym' cannot be used before it is declared
z.cs(288,13): error CS0841: A local variable `ObjSym' cannot be used before it is declared

Comment: @user234839: I didn't *just* suggest that you remove `<T>`. That's a starting point. You've already got a constraint of `K : IComparable<K>`... so use `x.CompareTo(y) == 0` instead of `==`. The error about a symbol not being used before it's declared is completely separate. It sounds like you've written a *lot* of code before compiling... it's generally a good idea to build regularly, and fix errors as and when they come up.

Comment: the first error(==) is because when i do "if (pt.symbol == processingValue)" because "symbol" is of type "T" or"K"(If i keep only "K" and remove "T") whereas "processingValue" is of type "int" and if i convert processingValue to type "K" then the Binary file i read using ReadByte() here, see this "K processingValue = stream.ReadByte();" creates problem because there is no conversion of "byte" to "K" type.Do you have solution for this ? After this solution i can solve it myself. How to make this byte work for "K" type ?

Comment: @user234839: Perhaps you should pass a `Func<byte, K>` into your constructor.

Comment: thanks.could you please bit explain more,BY modifying the answer you have given ? Would be a big help.

Comment: The error on doing so is : z.cs(30,30): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `byte' to `System.Func<int,K>'

Comment: @user234839: I don't think that's a good idea - it's a very long way from your original question. Basically you need to convert the `byte` from `ReadByte` into a `K`, right? So that's exactly what a `Func<byte, K>` would do. You would call the `Func<byte, K>` passing in the `byte`, and getting a `K` back. Note that Stack Overflow isn't an interactive debugging session.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50129/discussion-between-user234839-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: @user234839: No, I don't have time to do that now. I've given you plenty of suggestions now. You should take them and work on the problem on your own for a while, and ask a *new* question if you need to.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer from Jon Skeet, when using Generic types in your methods, you need to add the generic declaration to your methods:

For example:

```
public void Print_tree(Node<T> treee)
```

Becomes:

```
public void Print_tree<T>(Node<T> treee)
```

And

```
public Node<T> find_two_smallest(ref  Node<T> pmin1, ref  Node<T> pmin2)
```

Becomes:

```
public Node<T> find_two_smallest<T>(ref  Node<T> pmin1, ref  Node<T> pmin2)
```

Even if you don't use it in the parameters but in the body of the method, the method declaration needs to know about it, your method **huffman_node_processing()** uses `Node<T>` in it's body. Thus Visual studio tells you that it needs to know it in the method declaration. By changing the declaration to

```
huffman_node_processing<T>()
```

you tell C# that this method uses type `T`.